# Some objects turns black for a couple of frames in Cycles render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I am trying to render out an animation but I have a problem with a couple of the frames where some of the objects turns solid black. The only thing that's different in the problematic frame range is that I have animated some shape keyes. But I don't think that's the problem. If I render out one of the problematic objects in a single layer it works. If I view the whole scene in render mode in the viewport it also works fine. Almost all the objects in the scene are linked from other blenderfiles. Rendering with Cycles.

The animation is 350 frames long and the bugged frames is about 10 of them. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the solid black the same as background? check your shaders for animated parameters (colors, mix factor with transparent...). try to upload the .blend if possible.

Comment: thank you for your reply! it's a flat solid color. I actually figured out the problem. For the objects that I animate I have setup a bone that controls shape keyes using drivers. In my main project where I link everything into I use proxyes from the bones to animate the linked files. When I removed the animation it works fine (without black objects in the render). This is strange. Way around this bug/problem?

Comment: So you have a main file where you have animated proxies for linked armatures. Everything's fine without animation. Animated, some object (linked, with armature linked too from other files) turns black, but only in about 10/350 frames ? ouch! What happens if you link other objects from other files to the concerned proxies?

Comment: That's correct. It only turnes black in the frames I animate the object. Anyway. I ended up appending the objects instead of linking them. Still using the proxys. Everything is working fine now. Thanks for your reply.